# Providing master_ipv4_cidr_block and subnet range using terraform variables in GCP

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have created a private cluster in GCP using terraform modules.
As per the documentation here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#master_ipv4_cidr_block, I have configured the private cluster as below:

```
 private_cluster_config { 
   enable_private_endpoint = true   
   enable_private_nodes    = true 
   master_ipv4_cidr_block  = "${cidrsubnet(var.cidr, 28, 1)}"
      }
```

This cluster is provisioned in a subnet whose CIDR range is 10.15.0.0/16 (`var.cidr` is set to 10.15.0.0/16).

When I run terraform apply, I get the below error:

```
Error waiting for creating GKE cluster: The given master_ipv4_cidr 10.15.0.16/28 overlaps with an existing network 10.15.0.0/16.
"${cidrsubnet(var.cidr, 12, 1)}"
```

How do I provide the master_ipv4_cidr_block IPV4 address range and subnet range using value provided in `var.cidr` so that the ranges dont overlap?
How should the cidrsubent() be modified to suit this requirement?

Comment: Per the same document it says it must be /28 and that’s a limitation for private clusters. What is the error logged in stackdriver logs ?

Comment: The subnet VPC is 10.15.0.0/16 and the result of the cidrsubent() above is 10.15.0.16/28 which is a /28 address too.
But these address ranges are overlapping. But I'm looking for a way to provide these values using the same variable.
The stackdriver logs do not have any logs as this is a terraform script and the resource was not yet created in GCP.

Comment: Why do they need to be from the same var? The documentation at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters makes it seem like it is only needed for inter-VM communication and is connected via VPC peering connection automatically. You can likely just choose any private non-overlapping /28 subnet like `172.16.0.32/28` and not need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already identified, this is because there is a cidrsubent overlap, using a different subnet would be the best, but perhaps google cloud platform could help you more via a support ticket